# Berry Phase, Chern Number, Topological Insulators

Tags: solid-state-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I would like to understand the Berry phase and Chern number a bit better. For this, consider the SSH model, where it turns out that the Berry phase $\gamma_{+}$ of the upper band is given by $$\gamma_{+} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\Delta t\left( t_h + t_l\right)}{2E^2}dk,$$ where $t_h$ and $t_l$ describe the staggered tunneling energies in the SSH model, and where the energy dispersion $E(k)$ is given by $$E(k) = \hbar\omega_k^{\pm} = \pm\sqrt{\left( t_h + t_l\right)^2\cos^2 k + \left( \Delta t\right)^2\sin^2 k}.$$

According to our lecturer, the Berry phase $\gamma_+ = \pi$, but I have troubles seeing this..

Answer (score 0):

After some simple calculations, you can show
$$
\int \mathrm{d} k ~ \frac{AB}{2(A^2 \cos^2{k} + B^2 \sin^2{k})} = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\left( \frac{B\tan{k}}{A}\right),
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Using this equation and the relation
$$
\lim_{k\to \pm\pi} \arctan(\tan k) = \pm \pi,
$$ you can obtain the $\gamma_{+}$.

Comment: Are you sure that the second relation, $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\pm\pi}\arctan\tan k = \pm\pi$ holds? I obtain $0$ for the limit.

Comment: This arctan does not necessarily take a principal value, so it is correct in this case.
For example, when $AB>0$, the integrand function is always positive, so the value must change between $k\to 0$ and $k \to \pi$.

However, if you are not convinced, you can calculate it as $2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$.